# I have a long code which I don't quite understand, please help to break code into simpler statements

Tags: c#

Are the following methods do the same thing? I tried to break the statement in the first method into multiple statements for me to understand.

```
public static Actions KeysUp(this Actions actions, params string[] keys)
{
    keys.ToList().ForEach(k => actions.KeyUp(k)); 
    return actions;
}
```

And the `KeysUp` function:

```
public static Actions KeysUp(this Actions actions, params string[] keys)
{   
     List<string> listKeys = keys.ToList();

     foreach (var k in listKeys)
     {
        actions.KeyUp(k);
     }

     return actions;
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual error

Comment: Among other things, that is a simply dreadful title.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? `(this Actions`?, maybe `(k => `??? Please do clarify, make a concrete question instead asking for general advice.

Comment: Perhaps it would be beneficial to look at StackOverflow's [Ask] page , as it may help you understand how to better ask your question in a more well-received way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty inefficient and I don't know your type. I'll guess they're chars and you can substitute them with the other type if I have guessed wrong.

```
// keys.ToList() means
List<char> temp = new List<char>();

foreach (char k in keys)
{
  temp.Add(k);
}

// .ForEach(k => actions.KeyUp(k)) means (in context of your temporary list)
foreach (char k in temp)
{
  actions.KeyUp(k);
}
```

So the KeyUp method of your actions object is being called once for every key inside keys.

The reason for creating that temporary list is that the ForEach method is on List but not IEnumerable. In answer the question that my previous sentence no doubt raises in your mind, see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/).

A more efficient (CPU / memory, time) way of achieving the exact same outcome (minus the unnecessary garbage collection and delays) would be

```
foreach (var k in keys) 
{ 
  actions.KeyUp(k); 
}
```

or if you prefer it on one line:

```
foreach (var k in keys) { actions.KeyUp(k); }
```